# Listening to all events listed under the event hash in a Backbone view?

Tags: backbone.js

I want to listen up all view events added in the events hash, possibly like a common callback function.

```js
var ProductsView = Backbone.View.extend({

  events: {
    'click .toggle-button': 'showHideToggle',
    'click .remove-product': 'removeProduct',
    'click .selectall-toggle-btn': 'selectAllToggle',
    'click #prodlist-header .btn': 'doAction',
    'change .selectallprod-toggle': 'selectAllProdToggle',
 },
  initialize: function(){

    this.events.on('allevents', function(e){
      console.log('Event', e);
    });
  },

 });
```

I think there is some way with `delegateEvents` but I'm not sure of the implementation.

Answer (score 3):

You could override the [`View.delegate`](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-165) method that sets up the actual event listening and have it retrigger the event the way you wish.

For example,

```
delegate: function(eventName, selector, listener) {
    // create a bound function that wraps the real listener
    var newlistener = _.bind(function(evt) {

        // trigger the allevents event on the view
        this.trigger.call(this, 'allevents', evt);

        // call the real listener
        listener.apply(this, arguments);
    }, this);

    return Backbone.View.prototype.delegate.call(this, eventName, selector, newlistener);
}
```

You would then listen to an `allevents` event on the view :

```
initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this, 'allevents', function(e){
        console.log('Event', e);
    });
}
```

And a demo https://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/a8be77g7/

Answer (score 0):

If you want all events in a view to call the same callback you can just assign the same callback to them. Your question is not clear whether you want both, per-event callback + catch all callback.

```
var ProductsView = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
      'click .toggle-button': 'catchAll',
      'click .remove-product': 'catchAll',
      'click .selectall-toggle-btn': 'catchAll',
      'click #prodlist-header .btn': 'catchAll',
      'change .selectallprod-toggle': 'catchAll',
    },
    catchAll: function(e) {
      console.log('Event', e);
    }
});
```

Now if you want to catch all events and still have separate callbacks in your other views I suggest making a separate View that will listen to the body element events, since events bubble up they will reach body element ( as long as you don't stop the propagation ). I prefer that to changing Backbone Internals

```
var BodyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: 'body',
    events: {
        'click': 'clicked',
        'change': 'changed'
    },
    clicked: function(e) {
        // This will catch all click events on the page
        console.log('Clicked', e)
    },
    changed: function(e) {
        // This will catch all change events on page
        console.log('Changed', e)
    }
});
```

Personally I think it's a bit cleaner than overriding Backbone internals, a bit easier to understand since it's just another view.

Another thing is that if you're doing it in the 'initialize' you basically have to add it to every view if you want to catch events, which leads to unnecessary boilerplate. In the example here you just set up listeners once and they are picked up automatically, nothing needs to be added to the other views.

Of course in the BodyView you can still make it use only one callback for all events like it's done in the example above.